# How to get Google Place Autocomplete api result based on locale in android

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am working on an app which uses google place autocomplete api. 
I have successfully setup code and I am getting response as expected (in english). Now the issue is that my app allow user to set language preference to either hindi or english (for now more language support is on the way) and I am required to show the result based on the language user has selected.

I am aware of the google translate api but just keeping that as a last resort for now. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/ - Place AutoComplete